# Yii2 маршрутизация UrlManager

Tags: php, yii2

Есть такой сайт в котором 1 пользователь может выбрать в каком проекте хочет работать. Например: Заходит на главную страницу, выбирает себе проект и далее ему выводятся все его данные из базы (Товары, заказы и т.д).

Нужно сделать такой URL адрес **site.ru/admin/project_id/controller/action**
я могу добиться такого результата если передать в каждой ссылке параметр **ProjectId** и настроить **UrlManager** в **web.php**, но такой вариант мне не нравится, чтобы в каждой ссылке передавать **project_id**.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы **UrlManager** автоматически передавал **project_id** в поисковую строку?
как то переопределить **UrlManager**

Comment: Посмотрите https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/runtime-routing/, там достаточно хорошо описано

Comment: ЧТо плохого в том, чтобы передавать проект в ссылке? Его все равно как-то надо передавать. Если генерить все ссылки через url::to(), тогда проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Если ссылок много, то это проблема. Решил данный вопрос